# How can I link my project to the debug version of the MFC DLL in Release mode?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc, release-mode

I am working on a project which is in release build. I can't work on debug build for certain reason.

In the Release build, can I instruct Visual Studio to link against debug version of MFC DLLs, so I can step into MFC source code? If yes, how could I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You are voiding the warranty doing this.  It seemed to work okay though when I tried it on a sample MFC app.  Project + Properties, Linker, Command line is where to get started.  First put /VERBOSE in there and rebuild the project to see what .libs get linked right now.  You need to use /NODEFAULTLIB to disable the release versions of the .libs and add the debug versions of the .libs.  You also need to switch the CRT version, /MTd or /MDd depending on which one you use, Project + Properties, C/C++, Code generation, Runtime library.

Using VS2008 I ended up with these linker settings:

> /VERBOSE /NODEFAULTLIB:mfc90u.lib /NODEFAULTLIB:mfcs90u.lib mfc90ud.lib mfcs90ud.lib

Comment: Good answer, +1. I'm learning MFC as I go along, so I was kind of going for the "extra credit" question in trying to answer this one. I wouldn't have guessed to specify the .libs manually.